# How to implement java webservice which accepting request in xml format and response also in xml

Tags: java, web-services

I want to create Java webservice which will accept request in xml format and response also in xml.

I don't want xml in string format.My client is non java  technology(Ab-initio).

Request/Response  XML data have to be complied with specific xsd which will be in WSDL as type of request/response of operation.

ie. 'type' element of wsdl.

If anybody having idea regarding this, please share it.

### [WSDL created manually, which is importing xsd for request and response, My wsdl should generate as like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO4fe.jpg).

```
    <wsdl:types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/WS_WSDLFile/">

        <!-- Message request type from MessageRequest.xsd imported this is RS2 -->
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.org/MessageRequest"
            schemaLocation="MessageRequest.xsd"></xsd:import>

        <!-- Message response type from MessageResponse.xsd imported this is ISO -->
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.org/MessageResponse"
            schemaLocation="MessageResponse.xsd"></xsd:import>

    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally Myself have found the solution for this question.
**`JAXB`** API is crucial in this solution.

Steps:

1) I took the xsd ( for  which client will send xml as argument of webmethod)  and created Java classes using **'XJC' tool** in cmd.

**Execute command on Command prompt**:

D:\MyWorkSpace\MyProject>
xjc -d src MessageRequest.xsd

-- this command execution will create xml binding classess for request xsd.

D:\MyWorkSpace\MyProject> xjc -d src MessageResponse.xsd
-- this command execution will create xml binding classess for response xsd.

2) created same Java classes for response also using XJC tool.

3) After creation of java classes for request & response xsds
start creating JAX-WS implementation.

Note: In my case 'TX' is root element of 'MessageRequest.xsd' and 'Document' is rootelement of  'MessageResponse.xsd'

So My interface is as this

```js
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= Style.DOCUMENT,use= Use.LITERAL)
public interface MessageIntf 
{

 /*Interface which declaring  webmethod for webservice
  * Webmethod accepting XMLObject of 'TX' class  as a request and returning also XMLObject of 'Document' class.
  */
 @WebMethod(operationName="getISOMessage", action="http://localhost:8090/service/mService1")
 public Document getMessage(TX txObject); 
 
}
```

** My Implementation class **

```js
package pub.pkg;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import jax.serv.TX;
import iso.std.AcceptorBatchTransferV02;
import iso.std.CardPaymentBatchTransfer1;
import iso.std.Document;
import iso.std.Header3;

@WebService(endpointInterface="pub.pkg.MessageIntf")
public class MessImpl implements MessageIntf {

/*
This is a implementation class having implementation method   
*/
 @Override
 public Document getMessage(TX txObject)    
 {
  JaxUnmarshaller jx = new JaxUnmarshaller();// creating object of JaxUnmarshaller class
  Document doc = jx.getXmlData(); // binding xml into XMLObject 
 
  return doc; // returning response xmlObject to client 
 }

}
```

**My endpoint publisher class:**

```js
package pub.pkg;



import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class MessagePublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8097/service/mService1", new MessImpl());
        System.out.println("Service Deployed Successfully...");

    }

}
```

- Run the Publisher class as Java Application.
  and check the wsdl on browser on above url which is given in publisher class with appending "?wsdl".

eq.

http://localhost:8097/service/mService1?wsdl

- check the **type** element of wsdl.

Below is ***clienside implementation*** .. I am giving only Main class, marshalling/unmarshalling please do it yourself.

```js
package com.client;

import iso.std.Document;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import jax.serv.TX;
import pub.pkg.MessageIntf;

public class WebClient 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
 URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8097/service/mService1?wsdl"); // URL of webservice wsdl 
        QName qname = new QName("http://pkg.pub/", "MessImplService"); // Defining  namespace and service Name of webservice
 
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname); // creating service obj
 
       MessageIntf msgObj = service.getPort(MessageIntf.class); // catching the object from server in Interface 
 
     JaxUnmarshaller jx = new  JaxUnmarshaller();  // creating Unmarshller object
       TX txObject = jx.getXmlData(); // binding xml data in to  XML Object 
       Document domObject =  msgObj.getMessage(txObject); 
       /*  call the webservice method by passing  XMLobject and returning response XMLObject */ 
       
       new JaxMarshaller().createXML(domObject);
       // converting  xml object into actual xml  
       
       
       
 
    }
 

}
```